# tinymce inst.directionality

Tags: tinymce

I am stuck with an tiny issue with the tinyMce, and this is very urgent. In very brief, from tinyMce callback I get an tinyMce instance. Now I want to use this instance to set text-direction from "ltr" to "rtl" on the fly. But I don't seem to find and set the required property. Following is what I'm trying to do :

```
$('textarea.tinymce').each(function () {
    $(this).tinymce({
       init_instance_callback : "setDirection"
    });
});

function setDirection(inst) {
      inst.directionality = "rtl";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: [`init_instance_callback`](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/init_instance_callback) is deprecated as of TinyMCE3.x! You might want to use the [setup callback option](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/setup) instead.

Second: You can use the following code to easily apply the direction you want:

```
editor.getBody().dir = 'rtl'; // editor is a tinymce editor instance
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, thanks. I found another work-around and it worked. I will try yours as well. Thanks :)

Comment: please let other users know what you did - it might be helpfull to them too

Answer (score 1):

With TinyMCE v4.1.7, I added 'ltr' and 'tlr' option as toolbar for this small code modification required to be done in function LoadTinyMCE().

```
toolbar1: "ltr rtl | undo redo"
```